# Exercise III.12.2 in Hartshorne

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Here's Exercise III.12.2 from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:
Let {$X_t$} be a family of hypersurfaces of the same degree in $\mathbb{P}^{n}_{k}$. Show that for each $i$, the function $h^{i}({X_t,\mathscr{O}_{X_{t}}})$ is a constant function of $t$.

My question is, what does he mean by "family"? If I recall correctly, only flat and algebraic families have been defined. For me, a general family is just a morphism $X\to Y$. Is this what he means?

Comment: Yes. The family is parametrized by the scheme $Y = T$ and Hartshorne uses $t$ to denote a closed point of $T$.

Comment: See, for instance, examples III.12.9.1 thru 12.9.3.

Answer (score 2):

Since he asks for hypersurfaces of the same degree, note that they are parametrized by a subset of $\mathbb P H^0(\mathbb P^n, \mathscr O(d))$. This will be your $T$ (though it is not important to solve this exercise)

What you must notice, is that all hypersurfaces $X$ of a fixed degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$ have a ideal sheaf sequence of the form
$$
0 \to \mathscr O(-d) \xrightarrow{\cdot f} \mathscr O \to \mathscr O_X \to 0.
$$
Using this exact sequence and additivity of Euler characteristics, one can compute the Hilbert polynomials.